# openDatabase stuck

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, blackberry-webworks, opendatabase

I have a project with Blackberry Web Work, and this is my first time for mobile programming.
I want to create cache database using window.openDatabase 
But something is strange, I put alert after to show this database, but it didnot show anything.

I also put alert before and after this function, only show alert before this function
I try to put try catch error, but it still not show error message.

Need your help

Thx

Here is my simple code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            alert('not supported');
        } else {
            var shortName = 'mydatabase';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'My Important Database';
            var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
            alert("prepare to open database");
            var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            alert("open Database");
            // You should have a database instance in db.
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // Error handling code goes here.
        if (e == 2) {
            // Version number mismatch.
            alert("Invalid database version.");
        } else {
            alert("Unknown error " + e + ".");
        }
        return;
    }

    alert("Database is: " + db);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be related to the positioning of your try/catch statements. I rearranged your sample code and it is working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if (!window.openDatabase) {
    alert('not supported');
} else {
    try {
        var shortName = 'mydatabase';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'My Important Database';
        var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
        alert("prepare to open database");
        var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
        alert("open Database");
        // You should have a database instance in db.
    } catch (e) {
        // Error handling code goes here.
        if (e == 2) {
            // Version number mismatch.
            alert("Invalid database version.");
        } else {
            alert("Unknown error: " + e + ".");
        }
        return;
    }

    alert("Database is: " + db);
}
});
```

Keep in mind that openDatabase is not supported on all browsers. FireFox and IE will give you the 'not supported' alert, and Chrome and Safari will display the remaining alerts.

Here is the JSFIDDLE link to test the modified code http://jsfiddle.net/sdarya/0pkvLfpv/